# how to solve this error when using Hybridauth "An error occurred with <app name>. Please try again later."

Tags: php, hybridauth

I use hybridauth to connect with facebook, when i try to connect with face book i get the following error.

```
An error occurred with <app name>. Please try again later.

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
```

How to solve this?

also now it is getting called directly when i call the page but i want to give a link where the user can click and once the user clicks only the facebook login can be called in a separate popup window and making the parent page shade.

i am aksing this question here since i a new guy to PHP and only started to work on this three days.

thanks in advance

Regards
Tony

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have specified **app domains** in your Facebook app settings.
Facebook does not allow you to redirect to any other domains other than that you have specified.

in here https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[YOU_APP_ID]/summary

also check www and non-www version as well.